# (JTabbedPane) Transparence does not work on L&F different from Nimbus

Tags: java, swing, opacity, jtabbedpane, nimbus

I made this java JFrame:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Point;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.ScrollPaneConstants;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;
import java.awt.Component;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;
import java.awt.Rectangle;

public class ServerFrame{

private JFrame frame;

private JTabbedPane tabbedPane;

public static void main(String [] args){

    ServerFrame f=new ServerFrame();

}
protected ServerFrame(){

    frame=new JFrame();
    frame.setLocation(new Point(500, 100));
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setTitle("JSock Network System - v1.0");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);

    try {

        for (LookAndFeelInfo info : UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {

            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {

                UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {

        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        }
        catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e1) {

            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);

    frame.setSize(new Dimension(805, 462));
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.getContentPane().setMinimumSize(new Dimension(800, 600));
    frame.getContentPane().setMaximumSize(new Dimension(800, 600));
    frame.getContentPane().setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 600));
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

    tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane(JTabbedPane.TOP);
    tabbedPane.setForeground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
    tabbedPane.setBounds(new Rectangle(0, 0, 0, 333));
    tabbedPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(0, 0, 0, 0));
    tabbedPane.setFont(new Font("Segoe UI Semibold", Font.PLAIN, 12));
    tabbedPane.setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,0));
    tabbedPane.setOpaque(false);
    tabbedPane.setBounds(5, 95, 789, 333);

    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
    scrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
    scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
    scrollPane.setViewportBorder(new EmptyBorder(0, 0, 0, 0));
    scrollPane.setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,0));
    scrollPane.setBorder(new LineBorder(new Color(192, 192, 192)));
    scrollPane.getViewport().setOpaque(false);
    scrollPane.setOpaque(false);

    JTextArea textArea= new JTextArea();
    textArea.setOpaque(false);
    textArea.setForeground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
    textArea.setFont(new Font("Consolas", Font.PLAIN, 10));
    textArea.setEditable(false);
    textArea.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(0, 0, 0, 0));
    textArea.setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,0));

    scrollPane.setViewportView(textArea);
    tabbedPane.addTab("SERVER", null,scrollPane,null);
    frame.getContentPane().add(tabbedPane);

    JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("QTminer");
    lblNewLabel.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    lblNewLabel.setFont(new Font("Segoe UI", Font.BOLD, 71));
    lblNewLabel.setBounds(317, 6, 305, 77);
    frame.getContentPane().add(lblNewLabel);

    JLabel lblNetworkSystem = new JLabel("JSockNS v1.0 Inside");
    lblNetworkSystem.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
    lblNetworkSystem.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    lblNetworkSystem.setFont(new Font("Segoe UI", Font.BOLD, 22));
    lblNetworkSystem.setBounds(455, 68, 238, 39);
    frame.getContentPane().add(lblNetworkSystem);

    JLabel lblJsocknslog = new JLabel("JSockNS Log");
    lblJsocknslog.setBounds(720, 400, 85, 26);
    frame.getContentPane().add(lblJsocknslog);
    lblJsocknslog.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    lblJsocknslog.setFont(new Font("Segoe UI Semilight", Font.PLAIN, 13));

    JLabel background = new JLabel("");
    background.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Francesco\\Desktop\\841887-light-blue-wallpaper.jpg"));
    background.setBounds(-1121, -400, 2019, 912);
    frame.getContentPane().add(background);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

}

My Problem is that if i want to use Nimbus Look And Feels, my TabbedPane becomes transparent, and it's ok... but if i change to Metal or System Look And Feels, transparence disappears..

Here is an image to show this behavior.

[![Nimbus and Syste L&F][1]][1]

What am i missing?

EDIT:

LuxxMiner solution brought back transparence:

```
UIManager.put("TabbedPane.contentOpaque",  false);
```

before `frame= new ServerFrame()`

and:

```
scrollPane.setOpaque(false);
```

Now the problem is:

The TabTitle is not transparent anymore, with any L&F different from Nimbus.

Furthermore, i hate the bordeline of the tabbedPane, i would just leave the LineBorder of my scrollpane:

```
scrollPane.setBorder(new LineBorder(new Color(192,192,192)));
```

how to make not visible my tabbedPane borders?

Comment: Hi Francesco. We work differently from other forums. Please don't edit answers into the question. If you have an answer to your own question, write it as an answer (Use "Post your Answer" or "Answer your own Question" buttons at the bottom.) Also please don't write SOLVED in the title. The system itself will indicate if there is an accepted answer. You can accept your own answer after a time.

Comment: Ok, i'll do it right now, sorry.

Comment: No problem. Just takes a little getting used to that we are different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### SOLUTION

Starting from the solution proposed by LuxxMiner:

Do this:

### 1)

```
        //this sets the tabTitle:
    //PLEASE NOTE, use this exact syntax, new Color(0,0,0,0) each time)
    UIManager.put("TabbedPane.focus", new Color(0,0,0,0));  //removes focus rectangle.
    UIManager.put("TabbedPane.selected", new Color(0,0,0,0));   //removes background.
    UIManager.put("TabbedPane.contentOpaque",  false);  //removes background of tab content (not tab title)
```

these have to be the first lines before creating everything.

### 2)

```
tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane(JTabbedPane.TOP);

    tabbedPane.setUI(new javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTabbedPaneUI(){


        protected void paintContentBorder(Graphics g,int tabPlacement,int selectedIndex){} //removes tab content border.
        protected void paintTabBorder(Graphics g, int tabPlacement,int tabIndex,int x, int y, int w, int h,boolean isSelected){} //removes tab (title) border.
    });
    tabbedPane.setForeground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
    tabbedPane.setBounds(new Rectangle(0, 0, 0, 333));
    tabbedPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(0, 0, 0, 0));
    tabbedPane.setFont(new Font("Segoe UI Semibold", Font.PLAIN, 12));
    tabbedPane.setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,0));
    //tabbedPane.setOpaque(false); not needed
    tabbedPane.setBounds(5, 95, 789, 333);
```

this is the code for the tabbedPane.

### RESULT:

This image shows the result after these fixes. The border shown here is the scrollPane's one, set it to an EmptyBorder(0,0,0,0) to remove.

```
scrollPane.setBorder(new LineBorder(new Color(192,192,192)));
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

**Main answer:**

This seems to be some issue with the use of a `TabbedPane` in different LaFs. Put this before you do `ServerFrame f = new ServerFrame();`:

```
Color transparent = new Color(0, 0, 0, 0);
UIManager.put("TabbedPane.contentAreaColor", transparent);
UIManager.put("TabbedPane.selected", transparent);
UIManager.put("TabbedPane.unselectedTabBackground", transparent);
UIManager.put("TabbedPane.background", transparent);
UIManager.put("TabbedPane.borderHightlightColor", transparent);
UIManager.put("TabbedPane.darkShadow", transparent);
UIManager.put("TabbedPane.shadow", transparent);
UIManager.put("TabbedPane.focus", transparent);
UIManager.put("TabbedPane.selectHighlight", transparent);
UIManager.put("TabbedPane.lightHighlight", transparent);
UIManager.put("TabbedPane.light", transparent);
UIManager.put("TabbedPane.contentBorderInsets", new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0));
```

You can also replace `UIManager.put("TabbedPane.contentAreaColor", transparent);` with `UIManager.put("TabbedPane.contentOpaque",  false);`.

EDIT:

Also add this:

```
scrollPane.setOpaque(false);
```

and this:

```
textArea.setOpaque(false);
```

---

**Additional suggestions:**

1. Invoke the `ServerFrame` inside `EventQueue.invokeLater()` to prevent further issues:     `EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
       public void run() {
           ServerFrame f = new ServerFrame();
       }
   });`
2. Don't use null-layout, take a look at [layout managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) instead.

Comment: Your solution brought back transparence but look at this video i've just made (WMV 2MB, you must download to see it, embedded player does not work):

http://www76.zippyshare.com/v/fOfL6OLP/file.html

if i try to write in my textarea, all gets weird... ALSO WITH NIMBUS L&F at this time.

Furthermore, the tabTitle is still not transparent.. is there a way to set it so?

Comment: @FrancescoRizzi I found a solution for the first problem (see edit), I will inform you if I also find one for the second.

Comment: It works but now my tabbedpane gets borders, how can i set them invisible?

all i want to be visible is my scrollpane border:

scrollPane.setBorder(new LineBorder(new Color(192,192,192)));

EDIT: tabbedpane borders appear only with other L&F different from Nimbus

Comment: @FrancescoRizzi That's why I said "*I will inform you if I also find one for the second*"... - I'm working on it :P

Comment: @FrancescoRizzi I haven't found a solution that isn't sub-optimal yet, sorry. My only suggestion would be to copy my new code (see edit of the first code block) and set the border of the scrollpane to `Color.WHITE` - It won't be *that* ugly anymore, but it will still be there.